# How can I apply filtering and sorting results in a URL for Google Custom Search?

Tags: html, xml, url, google-api, google-custom-search

I am trying to sort and filter results using URL
the only thing that works is writing a search query in the URL.
here are some examples of what I'm trying to achieve but it's not working!

https://www.listoc.com/search/homes.htm?q=homes&sort=date:a:w
https://www.listoc.com/search/homes.htm?q=homes&sort=review-date:r::20091231

If anyone did this before please let me know!
I've read a lot in the guide: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search
but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Custom Search Element won't parse out url parameters in the page it is hosted on (except for 'q')

What you can do is either:

- Add an explicit sort option using the CSE control panel: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2549537
- Or, add a 'sort_by' attribute to the Search Element object: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

Comment: Thank you! it's worked for me. but it's too limited in Search Element Object .. I only can sort by date or relevance right?
I mean can I sort by year 2009 or 2008?
is that possible?

Comment: You can sort by any numeric structured data attribute.

To sort within a year, see the range syntax here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#page_dates
So something like 'date:r:20090101:20091231' to just get 2009 pages